# Count the number of methods in a Java file

Tags: rascal

I am trying to parse a Java file and count the method declarations in it. Right now I am using the following code:

```
import ParseTree;
import lang::java::\syntax::Java15;
import IO;

public int countMethods(loc file) {
    int n = 0;
    try {
        comp = parse(#CompilationUnit, file);
        for (/MethodDec md <- comp) {
            n = n + 1;
        }
    } catch ParseError(loc l): {
        println("Error at line <l.begin.line>, col <l.begin.column>.");
    }
    return n;
}
```

I am stuck with the error message that the CompilationUnit type is not enumerable. Now i wonder how I can get/iterate through all the methods?

Comment: Maybe you can use the deep match?
    `if (/MethodDec md := comp) {
            n = n + 1;
        }`

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int x <- l` means iterate over `l` and apply the pattern match `int x` on it, if that succeedes, bind `x` to the value. This means that for `<-` the right side has to be enumarable (lists, sets, maps,..). When you want to match all cases using a descendant match, you often want to use the `:=` match operator. Even when the right hand side is enumerable. See example below:

```
import IO;
list[list[int]] ll = [[1,2],[1,3,4],[3],[1,1,1,3,4]];
println("Pattern match on the children of ll");
for (/list[value] v <- ll) {
    println(v);
}
println("Pattern match on the children of ll and ll itself");
for (/list[value] v := ll) {
    println(v);
}
```

this outputs:

```
Pattern match on the children of ll
[1,2]
[1,3,4]
[3]
[1,1,1,3,4]
Pattern match on the children of ll and ll itself
[1,2]
[1,3,4]
[3]
[1,1,1,3,4]
[[1,2],[1,3,4],[3],[1,1,1,3,4]]
```

The difference is the candidates the pattern matcher tries.

For your specific example, you could also write it using reducers:

```
public int countMethods(loc file) {
    try {
        return (0 | it + 1 | /MethodDec md := parse(#CompilationUnit, file));
    } catch ParseError(loc l): {
        println("Error at line <l.begin.line>, col <l.begin.column>.");
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not this?

```
public int countMethods(loc file)
{
    try
    {
        return size([1 | /MethodDec md <- parse(#CompilationUnit, file)]);
    }
    catch ParseError(loc l):
    {
        println("Error at line <l.begin.line>, col <l.begin.column>.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are more roads to Rome ;-). I would not that it uses `<-` instead of `:=` (not solving the question). And a minor point, it builds an unnecessary list.

Comment: In my experience building such a list costs virtually nothing in Rascal (as opposed to, say, any variation of `[m | /MethodDec m := ...]`), but yes, the counting primitive is kinda missing in Rascal yet. In RcScript we can have `COUNT [X] IN SomeSet :- X IS MethodDec` with neither explicitly looping nor having this temp list. I might propose it as a Rascal feature...

Comment: @grammarware hey dude, updated the code formatting. Just paste the code and select code sample instead of using ` for blocks. Also, will `[1 | /MethodDec md...` not always return 1 to much?

Comment: `int countMethods(loc file) = (0 | it + 1 | /MethodDec md := parse(#start[CompilationUnit], file));` @grammarware this does not generate an intermediate list.